# Ms Integration Runtime data factory

Tags: runtime, integration, azure-data-factory

Kind of new with the integration runtime.
I had a pipeline running with no issues  but recently we had an AD upgrade and the local on premesis SQL db changed my user from 'bluecompany\joe' to  'redcompany\joe'
This has caused my datafactory to stop working properly . as it can't connect to the SQL onpremesis . 
I can't seem to find the place of where I can update this change?

Error:
Copy activity encountered a user error at Source side: Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) Node Name=ORG200016,ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectToSqlServer,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Server: 'org200016.bluecompany.com.au', Database: 'GroupRisk', User: 'bluecompany\joe'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Message=This user can't sign in because this account is currently disabled,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'.

any ideas would be very welcomed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your login account has changed, I think you will need to update the account in the corresponding linked service, where you entered your credentials for this database previously.

Be sure the test connection succeeds after you edit the linked serivce. Then the pipeline should be able to connect to your database again.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of ADF you're using, there are different ways to update your linked service:

1. login to https://portal.azure.com/ and find you data factory (if you don't have an account to login to portal, you need to find the admin who create this linked service and ask him to update for you)
2. if you're using v1 data factory, find the "Author and Deploy" where you should be able to find your linked service corresponding to your on premise SQL server.
3. if you're using v2 data factory, find the "Author and Monitor", click on the pen logo where you should be able to find your linked service from the "connections" tab, it will allow you to edit the linked service.

Thanks,

Eva